# How to get files in My Drive using Google Drive API v3?

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get list of files and folders in My Drive via this endpoint

> https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files

but the result returned is all my files (not same with My Drive).

Can I get correct list of resources like Outlook app ?

Regards,

**Solution**
To get items list in "My Drive", I have to pass this query in the request

> q='root' in parents

Comment: Not sure i understand the question.   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files will return all the files on the authencated users google drive account.

Comment: I want to retrieve a list of file and folder like My Drive :)

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean by My Drive the API is just going to return a list of strings

Comment: @DaImTo, sorry about my explanation.
I just want to get the current File/Folder in My Drive folder.
The current endpoint always returns all my drive's files

Comment: @haithngn q='root' working fine?

Comment: @DixitAkabari, yes it worked

Comment: In Node.js, it should be this: `await googleDrive.files.get({ fileId: 'root' })`

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to get the current File/Folder in My Drive folder. The current endpoint always returns all my drive's files

The Google Drive API just returns a list of files.  It has no concept of what your current file/folder is.  you can use the [Q param](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) to just return files within a specific folder, but you are going to have to know the name of the folder you want to list the files from.

Comment: @DalmTo,
Could you guest how Outlook retrieve the sample drive folders/files structure in thier app link this
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bk2LxlmeZFunEUGAxeXG29wwk3MRgeVW

Comment: @DalmTo,
I have found the solution to get drives in the My Drive,
just pass this query q='root' in parents

Thank you for your help